# Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)

Tags: android, mysql, json

[image]

Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: It is a NullPointerException. because your are getting String success 'null'. Google it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

For booleans, use if(success) or if(!success). not  success.equals(Object o). That is provided success is a boolean. In any case, whatever object that is, it was not initialized so it is null (if it's a boolean it's false). If it's a string initialize it and make sure it's not null. then you can compare. In any case, you cannot compare a string to an integer.
I am guessing, it's a boolean. So just use if(success).